# Solving a BVP with shooting method with differential boundary condition and initial condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on solving a BVP using the shooting method.
The initial conditions are θ(0) = θ0, dθ/ds(L) = 0,
The BVP is d2θ/ds2=s fg cos(θ). With fg being a constant 0.1, θ0 = [0, π] spaced 20 times evenly. L is the upper boundary of 4. Overall I do not know how to go about this with dθ/ds(L) = 0. I know it requires scipy.integrate.odeint. However all examples I have seen have the equivalent condition of θ(L)=.....

Comment: What does this mean `θ0 = [0, π] spaced 20 times evenly`? Is this the value of the initial boundary condition for θ(0)? Did you solve your problem or are you still looking for help?